# Dying after completing part of the challenge

Tags: ready-player-one

In the movie *Ready Player One*, the challenge involved following clues in a sort of treasure hunt.

If a player zeroed out (died in-game) after following all the clues, could they go straight back to the final challenge?  Would they need to collect the keys again?  Would they need all of the keys? Could they complete the challenges in any order?

Sorry if this sound like lots of different questions, but I feel like a single answer would provide clarity on each point. Let me know if this should actually be broken up into separate questions.

Comment: That's a legitimate question. Many people are familiar with the book; will an explanation from that suffice, or are you looking for a movie-only answer?

Comment: Absolutely a book answer would suffice. I don't think the movie even bothered with such details.

Comment: In the book, which I don't have in front of me, avatar-death would require you to start the challenges over.

Comment: @amflare - I don't have the book in front of me either, but didn't avatar death only require you to restart challenges you hadn't yet beaten?

Comment: Nope, it starts you over. When someone's avatar dies, it removes them from the scoreboard.

Comment: @amflare - I think you are misremembering, but I can't spoiler tag a comment. :p

Comment: I suppose we will find out once someone can get a copy of the book. And I've edited out the spoiler for the sake of others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the book, on avatar death, the player loses any Keys they may have, falls off the scoreboard, and is thus required to start over.

> I wouldn’t learn until later that the keys were nontransferable. You couldn’t drop one of them, or give them to another avatar. And if you were killed while holding one, it vanished right along with your body.
>   <sub>*Ready Player One - 0009*</sub>

> Instead, a few minutes after Shoto obtained his copy of the key, Daito’s name disappeared from the Scoreboard entirely. **There was only one possible explanation: Daito had just been killed.**
>  <sub>*Ready Player One - 0024*</sub>

This is further supported by the fact that

> When the Sixers detonated the Catalyst and killed everyone in the sector, every gunter and most of the sixers disappeared from the scoreboard

> “Wrong,” Art3mis said. “Check the Scoreboard. There are **still** twenty Sixer avatars listed there, below Parzival. And their scores indicate that every single one of them has a copy of the Crystal Key.”
>  <sub>*Ready Player One - 0024*</sub>

<sup>(all emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: This is also supported in the film. When Sorrento uses his weapon to kill every player, the leaderboards are wiped clean.